# Are there any Graphic Design e-commerce solutions?

Tags: logo, software-recommendation, business

I'm currently selling my logo design services on a community site, which works very well, and I'm also building a personal site to display my portfolio and find new customers. The community site works very smoothly: client orders, client gets instructions to provide certain information about their logo and then there's a messaging system for delivery of the final product or to make any revisions.

I would like to know if there's a software that works like this platform. I've been trying to recreate all the above by using woocommerce and wordpress but can't find a proper messaging system, and I can't find a way to request more info after a payment is made. I know there are solutions like BaseCamp but that forces a new customer to create an account with basecamp.

What are you guys using to run your online shop?

Thank you.

Comment: Not a way of working I'd advise. It's good that it's working out for you, but I greatly prefer having personal (mail, phone, irl) contact with my customers. Brings across so much more than just an online message.

Comment: *Design* doesn't typically work in the matter. Design is usually a service, not a product. As such, I don't think you're looking for an eCommerce solution, but rather a online project collaboration solution. Basecamp would be but one of many options.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for solid CRM solution. Probably it will be interesting for you:
http://www.bigcommerce.com/features/apps/

BigCommerce have integration with some strong CRM solutions, as well as accounting software, etc.